# How to replace directoy of another app package from assets folder

Tags: android, android-package-managers, rooted-device

I want to replace the directory which is present in another application package folder ( /data/data/com.***/directory to be replaced)

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Only app from package can modify it's packages folders.

Comment: Any possibility for rooted devices?

Comment: Only from console. If you can do that from other app, there is no possibility also for rooted devices. I was able to make such things, but it was on my custom Android image. There I was able to create low-level service which made what i want